# How to know new x and y as well as width & height after rotated

Tags: cartesian-closed-categories

[image]

Hi, I would like to know how to find out new x and y of a rotated rectangular in a cartesian graph, as well as the width and height. The x, y, width, and height originally is counted from the A point, which is one of the point of the yellow square in the picture. After it is rotated, A is a point of an invisible rectangular that is formed to contain the rotated square. Im making a game using JavaScript canvas and I am rendering my images using top left most corner, that's why I'm interested in the rectangular container after the shape/image is rotated. I appreciate any hints thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle after being turned by angle θ with vertical:

[image: img]

If you turn the rectangle by an angle θ with the vertical in a clockwise direction, then the coordinates of the points of the box bounding the rotated rectangle are going to be as shown in the image, where l and b are the vertical and horizontal dimensions of the original rectangle.
Hope this helps.